# Maximum wattage from a 125 amp panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I would like to know what is the most amount of Watts that a home can theoretically draw from a 125 amp system. I know that the formula is W=A X V, but since a home has 2 120V lines on "split phase", I believe.

Comment: Why are you asking this?

Answer (score 1):

24,000 watts continuously.  Such as racks of Bitcoin miners.

Or 30,000 watts if it's an intermittent load like an anti-misile pulse laser.

However, we're not done.  If you inject 24,000 watts of heat into a house anytime but the dead of winter, the home will overheat, possibly to the point of damage when combined with normal solar load.  So ther  must be air conditioning to remove that heat.  That air conditioning plant will dig into your total energy budget.

Comment: +1 for working lasers into the answer!